# Como simular clique em outro elemento HTML?

Tags: jquery, css

Nesta imagem abaixo ela tá normal agora, mas toda vez que eu passo o mouse por cima dela é colocado o elemento `figcaption` na imagem, esse `figcaption` utilizei para pintar a imagem de pretinha.

Aqui, a imagem antes de eu passar o mouse com seu `$('img')`

[image]

Após eu passar o mouse por cima ela fica com um `figcaption` por cima dela, pois utilizei esse `figcaption` para pintar de preto.

Imagem com o  `$('figcaption')` ativo.

[image]

Minha dúvida é: Como eu posso clicar na imagem e selecionar o `$('img')`?

Não quero selecionar o `figcaption` que está encima da imagem, pois com ele não vou conseguir abrir minha caixa de fotos.

```
$('img').bind('click',function() { $(this).$('caixabox').show('slow') } 
);
```

Comment: Coloque o código html também e o que foi feito, para ficar mais facil de ajudarmos

Answer (score 0):

Fica mais fácil com o seu código, mas posso te dizer que se você colocar no seu CSS apontando para o seu `figcaption` o seguinte CSS: `pointer-events: none;`, fará como quer. O seu `figcaption` não terá eventos de mouse, e ao invés disso, o click passará direto para o elemento de trás.

Exemplo:

```
figcaption {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```css
div {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 width: 367px;
 height: 314px;
}

figcaption {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 display: none;
 width: 367px;
 height: 314px;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 pointer-events: none;
}

div:hover figcaption {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYtPu.png" /></a>
  <figcaption></figcaption>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

Como lembrado por @BrunnoVianna, `pointer-events` não funcionará em versões IE abaixo do IE11.

Comment: vc tem whats ou skype? n to conseguindo ;/

Comment: Lembrando que o pointer-events só é servido por browsers IE11+. Fonte: https://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events

Comment: @BrunnoVianna Bem lembrado. Não posso falar por todos, mas eu geralmente não me importo muito com isso. Hahaha... Mas é bem falado aos que interessam. Vou atualizar a resposta.

Comment: @JessicaJadex [Pode entrar nesse chat para que eu veja como te ajudar melhor](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65072/jessica-jadex)

Answer (score 0):

Seria bom prover a estrutura do html pra gente entender melhor como fazer. Mas se você estiver usando a estrutura "padrão" para as tags `<img>` e `<figcaption>` (ou seja, considerando que o  `$('figcaption')` está no mesmo nível da imagem):

```
$('figcaption').on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    $(this).siblings("img").click();
});
```

A estrutura precisaria estar mais ou menos assim:

```
<figure>
    <img src="imagem.jpg">
    <figcaption>Figcaption</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Se essa marcação NÃO estiver parecida com a sua, poste a marcação e edito a resposta.

Comment: Tem skype  ou whats ou email pra eu lhe enviar o codigo? me ajuda pfpf

Comment: @JessicaJadex Já conseguiu a ajuda?

Comment: O qque é stoppropagation e siblings?

Comment: event.stopPropagation() impede que o evento "suba" pra outros elementos. Quando você clica em um item, ele faz um evento chamado "bubbling" e pode causar um clique indesejado em outros elementos. siblings você usa para selecionar elementos que são "irmãos" do elemento em referência (ou seja, estão no mesmo nível e dentro do mesmo nó).

Comment: Sobre bubbling: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing

Comment: Sobre o método .siblings: https://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Answer (score 0):

Sugestão, a imagem deve ser escurecida mesmo, ou poderia ser clareada?

Uma opção muito fácil é utilizar a opacidade do css, exemplo:

```
<img src='suaimagem.jpg' class='altera-opacidade' >
```

aí no arquivo css

```
.altera-opacidade{
    opacity: 0.5;  //sem o mouse em cima fica clarinha
    //filter:grayscale(100%); se quiser testar preto e branco
    //filter:blur(5px); //se quiser testar embaçado
}
.altera-opacidade:hover{
    opacity: 1.0  //com o mouse em cima fica normal e nao atrapalha o que voce quer fazer
    //filter:grayscale(0); //volta a cor
    //filter:blur(0px); //volta a nitidez
}
```

ainda sugir testar outros efeitos, com blur em vez do opacity, pessoalmente acho que fica até mais bonito. Aí, claro, no meu exemplo, você não vai usar mais o `figcaption`. Boa sorte!